# C# - Serilog - Enrichers leaving blank entries

Tags: c#, serilog

Figured out the basics of Serilog. Now trying to add a few enrichers so I can print username or machinename or classname, etc in the every log lines.

This is the code I have so far,

```
using System;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole;
using Serilog.Sinks.File;
using Serilog.Enrichers;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;
using System.Threading;
using Serilog.Context;

var outputTemplate = "{MachineName} | {UserName} | {Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u4}] | {ClassName} | {Message:l}{NewLine}{Exception}";
var Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: outputTemplate)
    .WriteTo.File("logFile-.log",
                  outputTemplate: outputTemplate)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Version", "1.0.0")
    .CreateLogger();

Logger.Information("Hello, Serilog!");

var position = new { Latitude = 25, Longitude = 134 };
var elapsedMs = 35;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Logger.Information("Processed {@position} in {elapsed} ms.", position, elapsedMs);
    Logger.Information("");
}

using (LogContext.PushProperty("SourceContext", "TestClass"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Logger.Information("Processed {@position} in {elapsed} ms.", position, elapsedMs);
        Logger.Information("");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.247 -05:00 [INFO] |  | Hello, Serilog!
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.287 -05:00 [INFO] |  | Processed {Latitude=25, Longitude=134} in 35 ms.
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.295 -05:00 [INFO] |  |
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.295 -05:00 [INFO] |  | Processed {Latitude=25, Longitude=134} in 35 ms.
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.296 -05:00 [INFO] |  |
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.297 -05:00 [INFO] |  | Processed {Latitude=25, Longitude=134} in 35 ms.
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.298 -05:00 [INFO] |  |
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.298 -05:00 [INFO] |  | Processed {Latitude=25, Longitude=134} in 35 ms.
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.299 -05:00 [INFO] |  |
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.300 -05:00 [INFO] |  | Processed {Latitude=25, Longitude=134} in 35 ms.
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.301 -05:00 [INFO] |  |
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.302 -05:00 [INFO] | TestClass | Processed {Latitude=25, Longitude=134} in 35 ms.
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.307 -05:00 [INFO] | TestClass |
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.308 -05:00 [INFO] | TestClass | Processed {Latitude=25, Longitude=134} in 35 ms.
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.310 -05:00 [INFO] | TestClass |
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.310 -05:00 [INFO] | TestClass | Processed {Latitude=25, Longitude=134} in 35 ms.
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.311 -05:00 [INFO] | TestClass |
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.312 -05:00 [INFO] | TestClass | Processed {Latitude=25, Longitude=134} in 35 ms.
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.313 -05:00 [INFO] | TestClass |
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.316 -05:00 [INFO] | TestClass | Processed {Latitude=25, Longitude=134} in 35 ms.
 |  | 2018-03-03 19:02:56.317 -05:00 [INFO] | TestClass |
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

From my understanding, I have to manually define the "placeholders" (`MachineName` or `UserName` or `ClassName`) in `outputTemplate` while creating the `Logger` object. I am not sure how to make these placeholders optional (i.e. without printing blank space in log line) if I don't need to use them. (I would not like to print class name for few lines for examples). Or maybe I don't understand the concept of Enrichers properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have 2 questions here:

1. Why Machine name and User name do not appear in logs?
2. How to make enricher placeholder optional?

> 1. Why Machine name and User name do not appear in logs?

Machine name does not appear in log because you have not added appropriate enricher - `WithMachineName()`.
Add following call to the configuration:

```
var Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
// ...
.Enrich.WithMachineName()
// ...
```

User name does not appear in log because you used incorrect placeholder `{UserName}` while it should be `{EnvironmentUserName}`.

Here is logger configuration that fixes both issues:

```
var outputTemplate = "{MachineName} | {EnvironmentUserName} | {Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u4}] | {ClassNameDelimited} | {Message:l}{NewLine}{Exception}";
var Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: outputTemplate)
    .WriteTo.File("logFile-.log",
        outputTemplate: outputTemplate)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
    .Enrich.WithMachineName()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Version", "1.0.0")
    .CreateLogger();
```

> 2. How to make enricher placeholder optional?

Placeholder like `{MachineName}` is just replaced with property value. If value is missing it's replaced with empty string. So in fact placeholder is optional.
However for output template like `"{MachineName} | Something"` this will result in `" | Something"` log entry. When you define such output template, nothing will remove constant string `" | "` from the result entry.

There is a solution for this problem, however it requires some efforts. The plan is the following:

1. Make a delimiter a part of of substituted property value.
2. Write custom enricher that checks whether underlying value exists. If yes, enricher will enrich log entry with original value concatenated with a delimiter. If value does not exist, enricher will not add anything, which will prevent appearing of delimiter without a value in log.

Here is a sample of such enricher:

```
public class DelimitedEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    private readonly ILogEventEnricher innerEnricher;
    private readonly string innerPropertyName;
    private readonly string delimiter;

    public DelimitedEnricher(string innerPropertyName, string delimiter)
    {
        this.innerPropertyName = innerPropertyName;
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    public DelimitedEnricher(ILogEventEnricher innerEnricher, string innerPropertyName, string delimiter) : this(innerPropertyName, delimiter)
    {
        this.innerEnricher = innerEnricher;
    }

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        innerEnricher?.Enrich(logEvent, propertyFactory);

        LogEventPropertyValue eventPropertyValue;
        if (logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue(innerPropertyName, out eventPropertyValue))
        {
            var value = (eventPropertyValue as ScalarValue)?.Value as string;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(new LogEventProperty(innerPropertyName + "Delimited", new ScalarValue(value + delimiter)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are extension methods for configuring enrichers:

```
public static class DelimitedEnrichersExtensions
{
    public const string Delimiter = " | ";

    public static LoggerConfiguration WithEnvironmentUserNameDelimited(this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrichmentConfiguration)
    {
        return enrichmentConfiguration.With(new DelimitedEnricher(new EnvironmentUserNameEnricher(), EnvironmentUserNameEnricher.EnvironmentUserNamePropertyName, Delimiter));
    }

    public static LoggerConfiguration WithMachineNameDelimited(this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrichmentConfiguration)
    {
        return enrichmentConfiguration.With(new DelimitedEnricher(new MachineNameEnricher(), MachineNameEnricher.MachineNamePropertyName, Delimiter));
    }

    public static LoggerConfiguration WithPropertyDelimited(this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrichmentConfiguration, string propertyName)
    {
        return enrichmentConfiguration.With(new DelimitedEnricher(propertyName, Delimiter));
    }
}
```

Finally here is a configuration that uses this custom enricher:

```
var outputTemplate = "{MachineNameDelimited}{EnvironmentUserNameDelimited}{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u4}] | {ClassNameDelimited}{Message:l}{NewLine}{Exception}";
var Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: outputTemplate)
    .WriteTo.File("logFile-.log",
        outputTemplate: outputTemplate)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserNameDelimited()
    .Enrich.WithMachineNameDelimited()
    .Enrich.WithPropertyDelimited("ClassName")
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Version", "1.0.0")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: That is gold!! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Doesn't this approach generate a new `ClassNameDelimited` property for every log event? If one uses a json formatter or pushes these logs into an aggregator, there is going to be a ton of noise and added bandwidth. Any comments on that? Would there be some other way of formatting the value without introducing extra properties into the logs or ignoring them?